# CollectionView nested into a ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, click, collectionview

I've tried to nest a CollectionView inside a ListView....
I was able to visualize all what i needed but now I cannot reach the click event on a single cell of a single CollectionView inside the list.
This is my xaml code:

```
  <ListView  x:Name="MainListView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <CollectionView Margin="10" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding singleList}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" ItemsLayout="HorizontalList">
                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Padding="10" Margin="10">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Frame BackgroundColor="White" Grid.RowSpan="2" CornerRadius="5" Padding="10">
                                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageName}" Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" />
                                        </Frame>
                                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Date}" VerticalOptions="End" />
                                        <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Source="shop" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        </CollectionView>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

I suppose I have to use the SelectionChangedCommand event inside the Collection, but I don't understand... how!!
Some help?

Comment: nesting ListViews is a really, really bad idea

Comment: How can realize instead a view like Spotify or Apple Music to show more elements on a single row in a page with multi lines?

Answer (score 1):

> I suppose I have to use the SelectionChangedCommand event inside the
>   Collection, but I don't understand... how!! Some help?

Not sure which part you don't understand, I will show you how would I use 
 `SelectionChangedCommand`.

Your `collectionView` binding `dataSource` to `singleList`, so the `singleList` should be a list of your `model`/`ViewModel`, let's say it `MyViewModel`, then in the `SelectionChangedCommand`, you can get previous/current `MyViewModel` you are clicking:

```
private void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    myViewModel previousModel = e.PreviousSelection.FirstOrDefault() as myViewModel;

    myViewModel currentModel = e.PreviousSelection.FirstOrDefault() as myViewModel;

    string previous = (e.PreviousSelection.FirstOrDefault() as myViewModel)?.Name;
    string current = (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as myViewModel)?.Name;

    //perform your own actions.
}
```

Update, code in my xaml:

```
<ListView  x:Name="MainListView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True">

    <ListView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>mono</x:String>
            <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
            <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
            <x:String>monorail</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </ListView.ItemsSource>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <CollectionView Margin="10" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" ItemsLayout="HorizontalList">

                    <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                            <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
                            <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
                            <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
                            <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
                        </x:Array>
                    </CollectionView.ItemsSource>

                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Padding="10" Margin="10">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Frame BackgroundColor="White" Grid.RowSpan="2" CornerRadius="5" Padding="10">
                                    <Image Source="Binding ImageName" Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" />
                                </Frame>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Binding Name" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Binding Date" VerticalOptions="End" />
                                <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Source="shop" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know the logic after... but the problem is that the CollectionView_SelectionChanged not firing... probably because is a nested object inside a DataTemplate....

Comment: @Blasco73 It fires on my side, I just add some dataSoure to made it work, I will show you my code in xaml!

Comment: Your code fire me too and works perfectly... but not mine.
And I've found the reason (but not the solution): if I use ItemsSource="{Binding singleList}" it not fire, with your <CollectionView.ItemsSource> on the fly works....

Comment: Ok, let me do some test.

Comment: @Blasco73 It works on my side and can you share more code of your singleList?

Comment: I've updated my Visual Studio and now works to me too....
I don't know what can be happened... I know only two things....
1) I've lost an entire day yesterday to find a solution
2) (the most important) I trashed your time.... and I apologie for this!!!

But the ColllectionView is in beta?

Comment: @Blasco73 Well, you solved it finally! Would you mind to mark my answer as I explained how to use SelectionChangedCommand. and the code also works. Then I can close this question on my side as it is solved.

Comment: @Blasco73 That's ok, we are here to help you with Xamarin forms problems. Yes,  ColllectionView is currently experimental as stated in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction).